# SSIS CSV IMPORT. I am getting following errors

Tags: ssis

- Executing (Error)
  Messages

> Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data
>   conversion for column "AddressLine3" returned status value 4 and
>   status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match
>   in the target code page.".  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "Source - sample
>   data-1_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[AddressLine3]"
>   failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition
>   on "Source -sample data-1_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source
>   Output].Columns[AddressLine3]" specifies failure on truncation. A
>   truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified
>   component.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing
>   file "C:\Users\laya\Desktop\sample data-1.csv" on data row 6.  (SQL
>   Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - sample
>   data-1_csv returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a
>   failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The
>   meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error
>   is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure. 
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: In the connection manager the size of the column to 500, open flat file source and let it adjust the columns automatically and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly points to data row 6 AddressLine3 column.
I see that you are using SQL Server Import/Export Wizard. What you would need to do is restart the process and this time when you chose the source as your Flat File in 'Choose a Data Source' page of the wizard, go to Advanced tab on the left and for your AddressLine3 column, increase the width to say 500 and then proceed with the rest of the steps in the wizard.

Comment: Thanks karthik i done this dut the data is shifting from addressline3 column to pincode column

Comment: The Advanced tab on the left helped me get through a sizing issue with the same message.  I needed to expand the field by one character to have the data fit.